# IE8 Rendering Bug: after javascript visibility-toggle, div content stays white

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, rendering

The page here (http://skergeth.net/slidingfooter/) contains a footer that slides up when you click on contact us. It then shows a contact form.

However in IE8 it slides up and the div containing the form stays white until it is hovered by the mouse.
I also tried the approach that the footer-div has overflow:hidden but since there are other elements inside the footer that should overflow (a menu that extends to the top), this is not an option.

I don't think it is a javascript but because I tried to delay the transition and made sure, the setVisible is called before it but with the same result.

I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 3):

add height:1% for the div which is after the div having the id="footercontent"
and it should work.(note: test it on all browsers)
this is happened when the IE didn't find a value for the height

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a zoom:1 and/or position:relative to #footercontent or any of the elements inside of it. This forces IE to set a hasLayout and fixes lots of css issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Solved it with:

```
#div-name * {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The div containing the form seems to load fine, since the "Contact Us" `h1` is visible. It's the form specifically that isn't being displayed in IE8.

Try playing with the display properties of the `form` element.

Comment: I tried replacing the whole footercontent with a simple h1 but this also doesn't show.
It's IE on Windows 7 beta, but I don't think it has anything to do with that.